# JAVA Determining the limit before stack overflow occurs, fibonacci sequence

Tags: java, loops, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to calculate the Fibonacci sequence using 2 different methods, one recursively and the other using a loop. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to determine the limit for each of the methods if the user is asked to input a number. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Recursion {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n, result1, result2, startTime1, stopTime1, startTime2, stopTime2;

    System.out.println("Please Enter A Number in between 0 and maxValue, will be calcualtred using 2 methods....");
    n = kb.nextLong();

    startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    result1 = fibRecursive(n);
    stopTime1 = System.nanoTime();

    startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    result2 = fibLoop(n);
    stopTime2 = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("\nDisplaying solution for recursive method: "+ result1 + " Time Taken (in nanoseconds): " + (stopTime1 - startTime1));
    System.out.println("\nDisplaying solution for loop method: "+ result2 + " Time Taken (in nanoseconds): " + (stopTime2 - startTime2));
    System.out.println("\nThanks for using our fibnoacci calculator. ");
}

public static long fibRecursive(long i)  
{
    if(i == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(i == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibRecursive(i - 1) + fibRecursive(i - 2);
}
public static long fibLoop(long k)  
{
    long a = 0, b = 1, ans = 0;
    if(k == 0)
        return 0;
    else if(k == 1)
        return 1;
    else
    for(int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    {
        ans = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = ans;    
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: have you tried surrounding the recursive method with a try/catch block that catches `StackOverflowError`

Comment: was not aware of any of this

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be try to catch the Error.

```
try {

} catch(StackOverflowError e){
        System.err.println("ouch!");
}
```

Comment: Have a non-recursive way to solve it i think is best (al most in java), but if you need to switch between algorithms, you could surround with try/catch the call to *fibRecursive* and if that throws the error call *fibLoop*.

Comment: Im still having problems implementing this into my code and I am getting a bunch of errors saying StackOverFlowError dosent exist (red lines)

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/joseluisdiaz/328e7103aafce4d558ff) describes a potential solucion. Take a look a StackOver**F**lowError that should be a lowercase f.